# How do I pass data to another view function for processing

Tags: python, django, function, redirect

I have the following code that i need to pass on to another function, `process_payment` for further processing. I've tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
def SubscribePage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PaymentForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            amount = '20'
    
            return redirect(process_payment(name, email, phone, amount))
    else:
        form = PaymentForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'subscribe.html', context)
```

Please advise on where i could be going wrong. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd need to see your process_payment(), but maybe the redirect should be like this:

```
return redirect('process_payment', name, email, phone, amount)
```

That is, assuming process_payment is a view you're redirecting to, and then those parameters would be defined in the view, something like this:

```
def process_payment(request, name, email, phone, amount):
```

If process_payment() is just a function, and not a view, then I don't think you'd be redirecting to it, you would just call it:

```
process_payment(name, email, phone, amount)
```